# How to apply the Transfer Theorem on $\frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$ and $\frac{1+z-\sqrt{z^2-6z+1}}{4}$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, analytic-combinatorics

> I am tasked to use the Transfer Theorem (see pictures below) to find asymptotic estimations of the coefficients of the OGFs described by $$A(z) := \frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$$ and $$B(z) := \frac{1+z-\sqrt{z^2-6z+1}}{4}.$$
> Remark: The pictures are taken from the [slides](https://sedgewick.io/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/AA05-AC.pdf) accompanying the Flajolet & Sedgewick book.

I recognise that $A(z)$ describes the OGF of the Fibonacci numbers and thus the radius of convergence is $\phi^{-1} = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.

Concerning $B(z)$ we see that the radius of convergence is $3-\sqrt{8}$.

However, I do not see how to apply the Transfer Theorem in these cases, as they are not in the required form $\frac{f(z)}{(1-z)^\alpha}$ or similar. Could you please help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Write $B(z)$ as $$
B(z) = \frac{{1 + z}}{4} - \frac{{\sqrt {(3 + 2\sqrt 2 ) - z} }}{4}\sqrt {3 - 2\sqrt 2 } \sqrt {1 - z/(3 - 2\sqrt 2 )} .
$$ Then $\rho  = 3 - 2\sqrt 2$, $\alpha=-1/2$ and $f(z) =  - \frac{{\sqrt {(3 + 2\sqrt 2 ) - z} }}{4}\sqrt {3 - 2\sqrt 2 }$. The term $(1+z)/4$ does not affect the high-order terms. For $A(z)$, do partial fraction decomposition and apply the theorem for each of the two fractions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not get how a partial fraction decomposition of $A(z)$ should look like, since the denominator $1-z-z^2$ can not be factorised.

Comment: Any polynomial can be factorised over $\mathbb{C}$ by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: With $\alpha ^ \pm   = -\frac{{1 \pm \sqrt 5 }}{2}$ $$
A(z) =  - \frac{z}{{\sqrt 5 \alpha ^ +  }}\frac{1}{{1 - z/\alpha ^ +  }} + \frac{z}{{\sqrt 5 \alpha ^ -  }}\frac{1}{{1 - z/\alpha ^ -  }}.
$$

Comment: Hint for $A(z)$: Check your book and/or slides for material on the singularity analysis of *merormorphic functions*.